# SQL Server trigger to insert multiple rows with different row-set

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

How to convert table with time series rows to column-based using SQL Server trigger?

Timeseries source table `variable_table`:

```
---------------------------------------------------
timestamp    var             property        value
---------------------------------------------------
1506598200   A01_NetOrder    49              10.0
1506598200   A01_NetOrder    50               3.5
1506598200   A01_NetRec      49              20.0
1506598200   A01_NetRec      50               4.0
--------------------------------------------------
```

Multiple rows will be inserted with trigger in destination table.

Destination table `var_column_table`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
timestamp      loc       property    NetOrder     NetRec
---------------------------------------------------------
1506598200    A01        49          10.0         20.0
1506598200    A01        50           3.5          4.0
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Trigger work around

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[rowColInsert]
ON [dbo].[variable_table]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @timestamp int
    declare @val varchar(125)
    declare @var varchar(125)
    declare @loc varchar(125)
    declare @col varchar(125)
    declare @cal int
    declare @sql varchar(max)

    select @timestamp = (select timestamp from inserted)
    select @var = (select var from inserted)
    select @property = (select property from inserted)
    select @value = (select value from inserted)

    select 

    select 
        @loc = (select left(@var, (select charindex('_', @var,0))-1))

    if exists (select timestamp from var_column_table where timestamp = @time)
    begin
        select @sql = 'update var_column_table set ' + @col + '=' + cast(@value as varchar)
        exec(@sql)
    end
    else
    begin
        select @sql = 'insert into var_column_table (timestamp, loc, property' + @col + ') values (' + cast(@timestamp as varchar) + ',' + cast(@loc as varchar) + ',' + cast(@property as varchar) + ','+ cast(@value as varchar) + ')'
        exec(@sql)
    end
 end
```

Please advise the work around to get the desired result. Note: inserted table has multiple records.

### Edit

1) The var in variable_table has multiple prefix like: V01, V02, V03...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the inserted table in a merge statement. Your trigger:

```
     ALTER trigger [dbo].[rowColInsert]
        ON [dbo].[variable_table]
        AFTER INSERT 
        AS
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

           MERGE var_column_table AS TARGET 
    USING
    (
    SELECT timestamp
    ,substring(var,0,charindex('_',var)) as loc
    , i1.property
    ,i1.value as NetOrder
    ,i2.value as NetRec
    FROM inserted i1 
    inner join inserted i2 on i1.timestamp = i2.timestamp and i1.property=i2.property
WHERE i1.property like '%NetOrder%' AND i2.property like '%NetRec%'
    ) AS SOURCE (timestamp, loc, property, NetOrder, NetRec)
    ON TARGET.timestamp = SOURCE.timestamp AND TARGET.property = SOURCE.property
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET
    TARGET.NetOrder = SOURCE.NetOrder,
    TARGET.NetRec = SOURCE.NetRec 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (timestamp, loc, property, NetOrder, NetRec)
    VALUES (source.timestamp, source.loc, source.property, source.NetOrder, source.NetRec);
         end
```

Please test if it works. Basically the 'inserted' table contains all of the rows inserted when the trigger fires. You can use the merge statement to perform upsert logic.

Comment: Working fine. What if, there is 105 variable in variable table. So that these variables will be presented in inner join and where clause?

Comment: I tested this on secondary table say "variable_table1" in place of inserted table, with procedure having your codes, and it's working fine, rows inserted into var_column_table but trigger is not inserting. Any guess why?

Comment: Also added, loc equality in where clause. i1.loc = i2.loc.

Comment: Please check if the trigger is fired at all. You can 'log' the execution by changing the trigger code to insert into variable_table1 select * from inserted. If you insert any rows into variable_table they should pop up in the variable_table1 as well

Comment: Trigger is firing. Confirmed with:select TRG.name, ETS.last_execution_time
from sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats AS ETS
     INNER JOIN
     sys.triggers AS TRG
         ON ETS.object_id = TRG.object_id

Comment: Trigger is inserting row into variable_table1.

Comment: Well I think you might have got it wrong with i1.loc = i2.loc. You do not need such a clause, also I do not know how you came up with it because the inserted table does not have such a column. The logic you were probably trying to put there in my code is located in the WHERE clause. Or are you saying that it works fine now?

Comment: Or maybe you do need such a clause if there are different prefixes in var column within the same property, I cannot tell from the example data

Comment: Exactly, i have multiple prefixes and you guess it correctly. But the surprise is if code is executed via procedure working fine.

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to insert new rows? Maybe they keep on getting updated with the same values

Comment: My actual table where trigger is applied is blank while procedure with same code is working. Trigger is not inserting/updating anything into table.

Comment: OK, so just to be clear that we are on the same page - if you create a trigger on variable_table, insert the data into variable_table via an insert statement, the modified rows will be inserted into var_column_table. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes. Data is inserted with external program after that var_column_table populating.

Comment: external_program-->variable_table-->trigger-->variable_column_table (not working) while external_program-->variable_table-->procedure (with your code)-->variable_column_table (working)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155568/discussion-between-pacodepaco-and-nkr).

Comment: Is their any way, we can add column name dynamically instead of hard coding it's name inside where and source clause?